# Как сделать столбчатую диаграмму с пометками на каждом столбце?

Tags: python, matplotlib, визуализация, seaborn, графики

У меня есть 3 файла txt с разыми данными :
file_1.txt

```
1, 22
2, 25
3, 26
4, 29
5, 32
6, 24
7, 13
8, 12
9, 24
10, 53
11, 12
```

file_2.txt

```
1, 22
2, 25
3, 31
4, 11
5, 22
6, 24
7, 25
8, 22
9, 18
10, 19
11, 22
```

file_3.txt

```
1, 24
2, 26
3, 34
4, 11
5, 21
6, 28
7, 30
8, 28
9, 18
10, 12
11, 9
```

Где первое число это время, а второе, через запятую это цена. Каждый файл содержит данные одного продукта. Эти продукты нужно объединить в одной столбчатой диаграмме, таким образом, чтобы порядок столбцов был всегда одинаковым, как показано на фото и чтобы эти столбцы отделялись друг от друга  правее, так же как на фото. И, чтобы на каждом столбце в левом верхнем углу, как на фото, была запись с именем продукта.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как это можно реализовать в Python? Буду благодарен любой информации.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот данные для таблиц:

```
class Animate():
    def __init__(self, file_name):
        self.file_name = file_name
        self.xs = []
        self.ys = []
        self.read_file()


    def read_file(self):
        with open(self.file_name, 'r') as data:
            lines = data.read().split('\n')

            for i in lines:
                x, y = i.split(',')
                self.xs.append(float(x))
                self.ys.append(float(y))
  


file_1 = Animate('file_1.txt')
file_2 = Animate('file_2.txt')
file_3 = Animate('file_3.txt')

print(file_1.ys) # Цена продукт_1
print(file_1.xs) # Время
print(file_2.ys) # Цена продукт_2
print(file_2.xs) # Время
print(file_3.ys) # Цена продукт_3
print(file_3.xs) # Время
```

Comment: ну у вас хотя бы черновик своего кода есть? и данные для теста привели бы в вопросе - лень генерировать за вас.

Comment: Вы можете продублировать те же данные, что я привёл из примера выше. Пускай колонки будут одинаковые, мне главное посмотреть концепцию того, как это всё реализовать  )

Comment: я много чего могу, но не буду это делать за вас.

Comment: Готово, добавил. Если не станете решать данную задачу, то буду очень благодарен за информацию о том, где можно об этом почитать.

Comment: Вы добавили все, что угодно, кроме того, что нужно. мне кажется, вам лень было поискать. нашли бы, например, это: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/plotting-multiple-bar-charts-using-matplotlib-in-python/

Comment: В том, что вы скинули, нет ответа на то, как на столбцах сделать пометки как на моей картинки.  И я не поленился, весь интернет облазил, но не  нашёл решение.

Comment: да ну бросьте. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70859757/how-to-add-vertically-centered-labels-in-bar-chart-matplotlib

Comment: Получается плохо искал ) Спасибо!  Попробую применить.

Comment: нет необходимости повторять одни и те же лейблы на столбцах, это перегружает диаграмму, вместо этого обычно используют легенду, она именно для этого и предназначена